# Completeness of theory of infinite sets

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

In the signature (R, =), where R is a 2-place predicate symbol, we consider the theory of infinite sets with an equivalence relation for which all classes are 2-element. Prove the completeness of this theory.

I have no idea how to do it. I know, that the quantification elimination method can work here. But I have a little experience of using it, so I don't know how to use it here.

Answer (score 2):

Quantifier elimination is overkill. When you're trying to prove that a theory is complete (or really, thinking about a theory at all) you should begin by trying to *describe its models* (or at least its countable models) up to isomorphism. For example, the easiest proof that DLO (= the theory of dense linear orders without endpoints) is complete is to show that its only countable model (up to isomorphism) is $(\mathbb{Q};<)$ - this is originally due to Cantor, and the simplest application of the generally-quite-useful [back-and-forth method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method) - and now simply note that by the [Downward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem) any $\aleph_0$-categorical (= only one countable model, up to isomorphism) theory with no finite models must be complete.

*(And more generally, any theory without finite models which is categorical in **some** cardinality must be complete.)*

With that example in mind, can you see how to describe the countable models of your theory? *(HINT: As a first step, if $\mathcal{M}$ is a countable model of your theory, how many equivalence classes must $\mathcal{M}$ have?)*